# Mysql Replication

Tags: mysql, database-replication

My current database design uses MyIsam mainly as the storage engine, I wonder if its possible to split some of the tables into MyIsam and some into Innodb in the same database. Reason of switching some of the tables to Innodb is because i need row-based locking which Innodb offers. I am not too sure whether this would have any effect on replication?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's totally safe for replication to have multiple table type in your database. I have MyISAM and InnoDB table, and i use replication over 7 slaves, never had a problem.

Comment: Thanks. Wat about mysql configuration. Can you a balance the load between the two storage engine?

Comment: If it's in the same database, don't think so. The load balancing happens between different MySQL Server, not tables.